# Partial install of OpenShift template resources

Tags: openshift

I have a Openshift template yml which will create the following objects "deploymentconfig, buildconfig, services and imagetag".
To create all the objects in the template , we can use below command,
`oc process -f openshift-template.yml | oc apply -f-`

Is there any way to create only **deploymentconfig** or **service** from the openshift template?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is possible using label selectors as shown in the example below:

1. Add a label to the resources you want to install e.g. the label `example.com/install: "true"` for the configmap **my-username**.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Template
metadata:
  name: user-template
objects:
- apiVersion: v1
  kind: ConfigMap
  metadata:
    name: my-username
    labels:
      example.com/install: "true"
  data:
    username: ${USERNAME}
- apiVersion: v1
  kind: ConfigMap
  metadata:
    name: not-installed
  data:
    username: ${USERNAME}
parameters:
- description: USERNAME for authentication
  from: '[A-Z0-9]{8}'
  generate: expression
  name: USERNAME
```

2. Specify the selector when executing the `oc create` command, for example:

```
$ oc process -f template.yaml -p USERNAME=rmaloku \
  | oc create --selector example.com/install=true -f -

configmap/my-username created
```

From the output, we can see that only the labeled resource is installed.

---

Description of the selector flag:

```
 --selector='': Selector (label query) to filter on, supports '=', '==', and '!='.(e.g. -l key1=value1,key2=value2)
```